# How do you inject object into an AuthFilter which requires @context for Jersey / Dropwizard

Tags: jersey, dropwizard, dynamic-feature, dropwizard-guice

I'm trying to figure out how to inject an object when registering a AuthDynamicFilter in jersey.

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application<Configuration> {
   public void run(Configuration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
      ...

      environment.jersey().register(new AuthDynamicFeature(CustomAuthFilter.class));   
      ...
   }
}
```

CustomAuthFilter

```
@PreMatching
public class CustomAuthFilter<P extends Principal> extends AuthFilter<String, P> {
   private final Object identity;

   @Context
   private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

   @Context
   private HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse;

   public LcaAuthFilter(Identity identity) {
     this.identity = identity;
   }

   @Override
   public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
       ...identity.process(httpServletRequest)
   }

}
```

The above code won't compile because there is no way to inject the Identity Object when creating the CustomAuthFilter.

If you go with:

```
   environment.jersey().register(new AuthDynamicFeature(new CustomerAuthFilter(new Identity())));
```

In this case, httpServletRequest will be set to null.

The only way I could figure out how to get around this is to not even use AuthDynamicFeature and just go with a normal Filter and inject it that way which is fine.  I'm wondering how would you do it with a AuthDynamicFeature.

I'm still new to dropwizard and jersey so please bear with me.  Some concepts that I might be messing.

Any Advice Appreciated,
Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that does exactly that. Annotate the constructor with `@Inject`:

```java
@PreMatching
public class CustomAuthFilter<P extends Principal> extends AuthFilter<String, P> {
   private final Identity identity;

   @Context
   private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

   @Context
   private HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse;

   // Annotate the ctor with @Inject
   @Inject
   public LcaAuthFilter(Identity identity) {
     this.identity = identity;
   }

   @Override
   public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
       ...identity.process(httpServletRequest)
   }

}
```

Tell Jersey's dependency injection mechanism to inject the `identity` with a value you provide:

```java
Identity identity = getTheIdentity();
environment.jersey().register(new AbstractBinder() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(identity).to(Identity.class);
    }
});
environment.jersey().register(new AuthDynamicFeature(CustomAuthFilter.class));
```

If `identity` is only known at runtime, use a `Supplier<Identity>` instead (adapt your constructor 
as well):

```java
Supplier<Identity> identity = getTheIdentitySupplier();
environment.jersey().register(new AbstractBinder() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(identity).to(new TypeLiteral<Supplier<Identity>>(){});
    }
});
environment.jersey().register(new AuthDynamicFeature(CustomAuthFilter.class));
```